# clone a KeyboardEvent event including currentTarget

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to shallow clone a KeyboardEvent event. I tried:

```
let eclone=new KeyboardEvent('', e);
```

which copied most but not all properties. Especially, It did not copy the 'currentTarget' or 'target' properties

I tried to add:

```
eclone.currentTarget=e.currentTarget;
```

but this throws 'Cannot assign to read only property 'currentTarget' of object '#'

How can I clone this event ? can I somehow temporarily remove read-only on eclone.currentTarget ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by creating or cloning `KeyboardEvent`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`EventTarget.dispatchEvent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent) where created `event` is passed as parameter. Note, the first parameter passed to [`KeyboardEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/KeyboardEvent) is expected to be a string representing the name of the event.

```js
var e = new KeyboardEvent("keydown", {key:"g"});

window.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  if (!event.isTrusted) {
    console.log(event.target === window);
    document.body.textContent = e.key;
  }
});
// set `event.target` of `e` to `window`
window.dispatchEvent(e);
```